# "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead." How can i solve this

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api

i'm trying to do with API Call. I got error every time trying to do API Call.

**typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))**

this is what i see when simulate my code in console.

Here is json format i try to call in my app. [Click](https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=tr&apiKey=1ea9c2d2fbe74278883a8dc0c9eb912f)

**My Model**

```
struct Article: Codable {
    let author: String
    let title, articleDescription: String
    let url: String
    let urlToImage: String
    let publishedAt: Date
    let content: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case  author, title
        case articleDescription = "description"
        case url, urlToImage, publishedAt, content
    }
}
```

**and This is my API Call function.**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var article = [Article]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        jsonParse {
            print("success")
        }
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }


    
    
    func jsonParse(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=tr&apiKey=1ea9c2d2fbe74278883a8dc0c9eb912f")
 
        let task =  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }else {
                
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Article].self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print(data as Any)
                        print("success")
                        self.jsonParse {
                            print("success")
                        }
                    }
                   
                }catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
          
            }
            
        }
        task.resume()
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Can you help me about my problem, thank you.

Comment: You will get a better error if you use “print(error)” instead of the localized description version

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'm going to do this and edit my question.

Comment: Obviously you don’t have an array at the top level so change the decoding call

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry i didn't understand, can you explain little bit more please

Comment: Your json Isn't an `[Article]`, it's a another struct, which has an `[Article]` property. In other words, you are missing on level in the JSON hierarchy.

Comment: Which line is failing? The call to `JSONDecoder.decode()`? (You might want to add extra print statements that let you see the context of your messages.) If the error is in the decode call, that suggests that your JSON isn't structured the same as your Codable structs. Try converting your data to a string and logging it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common mistake: You ignore the root object, a dictionary. With `Decodable` it's mandatory to decode the JSON from the top.

Add this struct

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}
```

and decode

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data!)
```

And **never** `print(error.localizedDescription)` in a Codable catch block. Always write this

```
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but now i got new error like this:                                                           typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "articles", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "publishedAt", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: **"Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))**

Comment: The error means what it says. The value for `publishedAt` is a string, not a date. To decode it as `Date` you have to add an appropriate date decoding strategy. The default date decoding strategy is `timeIntervalSince1970` which expects a `Double`.

Comment: Thank you again, i solve my problem. Thanks for your effort a lot really.